# Prove that the Iwata function is Submodular

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

The Submodularity property for $f: 2^V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as:

$f(X) + f(Y) \geq f(X \cup Y) + f(X \cap Y)$ where $X, Y \subseteq V$

While the Iwata function is defined as:

$f(X)=|X||X^c| - \sum_{k \in X}({5k-2n})$

where $X\subseteq V$, and $V=\{1,...,n\}$

To prove that this function is Submodular I would go using the proof by induction. It is clear to see that the Submodularity property fulfills for $X=\{\emptyset\}$ since $f(\{\emptyset\})=0$ then the property holds for the empty set. Proving it for $X$ having $k$ elements is more tricky though. Does $k$ apply only to $X$ or to $Y$ as well? how many elements overlap? it is not clear to me by simply choosing an arbitrary $k$ then prove that the Submodularity property holds and then that it holds for $k+1$ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a direct proof with $X=A\cup B$, $Y=B\cup C$ where $A,B,C$ are disjoint.
Note that the left hand side is
$$\begin{align}f(X)+f(Y)&=f(A\cup B)+f(B\cup C) \\&= (|A|+|B|)(n-|A|-|B|)+(|B|+|C|)(n-|B|-|C|)\\&\quad-\sum_{k\in A}(5k-2n)-2\sum_{k\in B}(5k-2n)-\sum_{k\in C}(5k-2n)\end{align}  $$
whereas the right hand side  is 
$$\begin{align}f(X\cup Y)+f(X\cap Y)&=f(A\cup B\cup C)+f(B) \\&= (|A|+|B|+|C|)(n-|A|-|B|-|C|)+|B|(n-|B|)\\&\quad-\sum_{k\in A}(5k-2n)-2\sum_{k\in B}(5k-2n)-\sum_{k\in C}(5k-2n)\end{align}.$$
If you subtract, most will cancel (it should turn out that the difference is $|A||C|\ge 0$).
Apparently, the $\sum (5k-2n)$ stuff is a bit of a red herring. Anything of the form $\sum_{x\in X} g(x)$ could be replaced for that sum

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it is very enlightening :) but the Iwata function has $|X||X^c|$ and not just $|X|$ so I can't see where this bit is ... and specially what the resulting magnitude is to be able to compare, and how to achieve the result without making any assumptions on the cardinality of $A, B, C$ w.r.t. $V$

Comment: $X=A\cup B$, $\ |X|=|A|+|B|$ because $A,B$ are disjoints. $|X^c|=(n-|A|-|B|)$. All there are included in the answer.

Comment: Ah sorry true, did not see it. Thank you!